# Does this infinite product converge? And how to express it neatly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

First of all, does this product have a "nicer" functional form--i.e., analogous to how you can write geometric sums in a nice closed expression:

$$(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n)$$

Secondly, does this converge to something as n goes to infinity?

Comment: It converges iff $x$ is a nonnegative integer. Can you see what is special about this particular case?

Comment: This is a “falling factorial”, and is sometimes written $(x)_{n+1}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: I mean, I suppose something like $\prod_{i=0}^n (x-i)$ works and looks slightly better. And I'm pretty sure it cannot converge to anything unless if $x\in\mathbb{N}$, in which case one of the products is 0, so the limit is 0, as otherwise we will just get a bunch of terms, all nonzero, that will eventually go in absolute value to infinity.

Comment: @SteveKass Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.  I am interested in case where x is positive real valued.

Comment: Ignoring terms which are zero, an infinite product $\prod\limits_{i=0}^\infty a_i$ converges iff the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \log(a_i)$ converges.  This would imply that $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}\log(a_i)=0$ implying that $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} a_i=1$.  You have however $(x-n)$ does *not* converge to $1$, so the form cannot possibly converge to anything (*except zero if you don't ignore zero terms as is otherwise common to do for infinite products*).

Comment: If you consider the limit as $n$ goes to infinity and $x$ is not an integer, you  include more and more factors with greater and greater absolute value (once $n$ exceeds $x$), so the limit diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is a non-negative integer $m$, the product is equal to $0$ for all $n\ge m$ and therefore converges to $0$. In all other cases it fails to converge.

To see this, let $a_n=x^{\underline{n+1}}=\prod_{k=0}^n(x-k)$. (Another notation is $(x)_{n+1}$, but I don’t care for it.) There is an $m$ such that $(x-m)<-2$, and clearly $|a_{n+1}|>2|a_n|$ for $n\ge m$, so

$$|a_n|\ge 2^{n-m}|a_m|$$

for $n\ge m$.